# iOS Access denied when trying to download file from Amazon S3

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have been able to upload/download files from an iOS app with no problems. I have recently created a new bucket to store new image files. When I try to download a file from the recently created bucket I get the following error:

```
[Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain 
Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain error 1.)" 
UserInfo=0x183a7760
{HostId=ST+d3VvsztpkvPfxLvYeS6b+pukUHuVzKJElYPWVYHYpK0wNjNAlEttJHFta2ApUYhFTTGzhqEg=, 
Code=AccessDenied, 
Message=Access Denied, 
RequestId=662BA8AD07272A0C}]
```

I have correctly added the new bucket to my IAM policy as shown below

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::oldbucket1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::oldbucket2/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::newbucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy is valid and worked before with my old buckets.

Comment: Can you please show me the image URL

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/yellup-thumbnails/AEDF9574-17CE-44A0-92C8-ABEFEA579115-2977-000009CF8BA2E848.jpeg
@NimitParekh I am downloading the files using the AWS iOS SDK not the public URL.

Comment: make sure you access image using the same case as it was uploaded and is stored on S3.
for example, if you uploaded image_name.JPG, you should use the same name, but not image_name.jpg

Comment: Actually the problem is not in the policy at all, I just had to change the bucket name. Thanks!